# while loop inside foreach loop problems

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to update a range of dates with a `Shift_ID` but the `Shift_ID` that is entered depends upon what day of the week it is. So, for example, if I have a range of dates `$from = "2012-12-01"` `$to = "2012-12-28"` I'm trying to make it so that I can select a check box (for example: `value="Fri" name = "offdays[]"`) to indicate what day is an `offdays`. If an `offdays` is matched with a day in the set range, then the `Shift_ID = "6"` otherwise it is a work day and `Shift_ID = "3"`

Hopefully this will all make sense in a minute, I'm doing my best to explain it as well as give you some useful variables.

So here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if(isset($_POST['offdays']))
        {
        //$off is set through the config settings//
        $shift = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['shift']);
        $from = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
        $to = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);
        $emp_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['emp_id']);

        foreach($_POST['offdays'] as $checkbox)
            {
            echo "Checkbox: " . $checkbox . "<br>";//error checking
            $sql = ("SELECT Date FROM schedule WHERE (Date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to') AND (Emp_ID = '$emp_id')");

            if(!$result_date_query = $mysqli->query($sql))
                {
                echo "INSERT ERROR 1 HERE";
                }
                echo "SELECT SQL: " . $sql . "<br>";//error checking

                while($row = $result_date_query->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                    echo "Date: " . $row['Date'] . "<br>";//error checking
                    $date = date('D',strtotime($row['Date']));

                    if($date == $checkbox)
                        {
                        echo "MATCHED! Date: " . $date . " Checkbox: " . $checkbox . "<br>";//error checking
                        $sql = ("UPDATE schedule SET Shift_ID = '$off' WHERE Date = '" . $row['Date'] . "' AND Emp_ID = '$emp_id'");

                        if(!$result_update_offdays_query = $mysqli->query($sql))
                            {
                            echo "INSERT ERROR 2 HERE";
                            }
                            echo "UPDATE DAYS OFF SQL: " . $sql . "<br><br>";//error checking
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        echo "NOT MATCHED! Date: " . $date . " Checkbox: " . $checkbox . "<br>";//error checking
                        $sql = ("UPDATE schedule SET Shift_ID = '$shift' WHERE Date = '" . $row['Date'] . "' AND Emp_ID = '$emp_id'");

                        if(!$result_update_shift_query = $mysqli->query($sql))
                            {
                            echo "INSERT ERROR 3 HERE";
                            }
                            echo "UPDATE SHIFT SQL: " . $sql . "<br><br>";//error checking
                        }               
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
```

When I look at my printed echo statements, everything is perfect! When a date lands on a Friday, it shows that it's entering `Shift_ID = "6"` and any other day shows `Shift_ID = "3"`. The problem is the tables don't reflect what my statements are telling me, they all just get updated to `Shift_ID = "3"`.

In the end I want to be able to select more than one `offdays`, but when I select more than one, it overwrites my previous day during the next loop, which makes sense.

I've got no idea what is going on, if anyone can give me a clue, I would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE:** When I add `exit;` after the days off update, like this:

```
echo "UPDATE DAYS OFF SQL: " . $sql . "<br><br>";//error
exit;
```

it does update the day off to `Shift_ID = "6"`, so it must be something happening after that.

**EDIT:** It appears as though the problem was with user permissions. I can't explain why, but after deleting the user and creating a new one with full permissions, things started to work. I chose @andho's answer as he helped me get to the answer in the chat forum and also added a way to clean up my code.

Comment: For your own sake, you really should escape the `$shift`, `$to`,`$from` and `$emp_id` entries `$emp_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['emp_id']);`

Comment: 14 hours without an answer, I am completely stumped and obviously everyone else is too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't solve your issue, but simplifies the solution!

if your offdays variable is as follows: `$offdays = array('Fri', 'Sun');`

You can first set all dates in range to $shift in one query:

```
UPDATE Schedule SET Shift_ID = '$shift' WHERE Date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND Emp_ID = '$emp_id'
```

Then you can loop through the `foreach ($offdays as $offday) {` and update those offdays:

```
UPDATE Schedule SET Shift_ID = '$off' WHERE Date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND Emp_ID = '$emp_id' AND DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%a') = '$offday'
```

That should update all the `$offday's` in the range to `$off`.

This will reduce your loops and queries, which gives leaner code.

Comment: Serious respect for all the help you gave me in chat, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = ("SELECT `Date` FROM schedule WHERE (`Date` BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to') AND (Emp_ID = '$emp_id')");
```

Use backtick(`) to all the fieldname date because it is reserved in mysql.

Comment: I'm not sure why my comment was deleted? Anyways, Thank you for the reply, I have added the backticks as you suggested. This doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.